# How to fix thin faces warning of "Mesh: 3d printing toolbox" add-on

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I have Run "check all" and gives this warning. How to fix the thin faces warning? What should I do on the medical object?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I have deleted it.

Comment: You shouldn't delete it. Also rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Answer (score -1):

**Zero faces mean they are so close together the area equals zero.**

Here's a video tutorial that may help explain the options of 3D Printing Tool Box which you can use before exporting out of blender to check the stl.

Blender Mesh Fixing | 3D Printing Tool Box Explained
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rgrLWFUjlk

```
Time Stamps:
    0:00 - The 3D Print Tool Box | Blender Mesh Analysis.
    1:03 - How To Scale By Volume & Bounds.
    2:40 - Non-Manifold Edge Explained.
    3:35 - Bad Contig. Edges Explained.
    4:20 - Intersect Face Explained.
    5:34 - Zero Faces Explained. 
    6:19 - Zero Edges Explained. 
    7:18 - Non-Flat Faces Explained. 
    9:10 - Thin Faces Explained.
    10:10 - Sharp Edge Explained. 
    11:30 - Overhang Face Explained. 
    12:15 - A Little Bug To Watchout For.
    13:19 - Automatic Blender Mesh Fixing & Exporting.
    14:15 - Mesh Design Things To Keep In Mind.
```